# How to create a column based on the min date of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, min

[image]

```
print (df)
      Event1     Event2     Event3
0  7/27/2014        NaN        NaN
1   3/5/2016        NaN   2/1/2013
2  5/13/2017  5/10/2013        NaN
3        NaN        NaN  4/28/2014
4        NaN  5/12/2013   3/6/2016
5        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Hi all,

I have 3 columns in my pandas dataframe, I want to create a new column to show the minimum date among `Event 1`, `Event 2`, and `Event 3`. If there is no date in all the 3 columns, then print `NaN` as shown in the last row of the screenshot above.

The last column in the screenshot (New column) is the expected output. Any advise or help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter columns with `Event` with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), convert to datetimes and get minimal values, last for original format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['new'] = (df.filter(like='Event')
               .apply(pd.to_datetime)
               .min(axis=1)
               .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
print (df)
      Event1     Event2     Event3         new
0  7/27/2014        NaN        NaN  07/27/2014
1   3/5/2016        NaN   2/1/2013  02/01/2013
2  5/13/2017  5/10/2013        NaN  05/10/2013
3        NaN        NaN  4/28/2014  04/28/2014
4        NaN  5/12/2013   3/6/2016  05/12/2013
5        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
```